# How to remove empty characters from string perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, parsing, whitespace

I need to remote spaces, new line chars, tabs and so on. I have tried to do this in different ways.

```
 $entry =~ s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/; 
 $entry =~ /^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+/;
 chomp($entry);
```

As for first line regex, it doesn't remove null characters \0, I am getting string with null value after this.  Second regex doesn't help too.
Please help to delete all spaces from string and if string is empty it should not pass barrier

```
if ($entry)
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. What are you trying to remove or what are you trying to keep? If it's just whitespace, then `s/\s//g` will do it

Answer (score 4):

To remove all non-prinable characters (of which \0 is one) and all whitespace characters, do:

```
s/[[:^print:]\s]//g
```

To remove them from the beginning and end, do:

```
s/\A[[:^print:]\s]|[[:^print:]\s]\z/;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, how can I leave spaces inside string for instance I have <aricle name="Hello"> I need to delete spaces and non printable chars at corners but not inside string, now I am getting <articlename="Hello">

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all white characters (spaces, tabs) then doing

> $entry =~ s/\s//g

should be enough. I'm not fully clear on what else do you want to remove.
An empty string will not pass through:

> if ($entry)

Comment: `\s`  don't  remove the newlines.